# Change background color of NSButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

I have an NSButton in a mac application whose colour I'd like to change programatically but nothing I tried seems to work. I tried to create an output on the NSButtonCell and set the background color there but that didn't work either. Any code snippets would be helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard Aqua (pill-shaped) buttons are drawn by the system. They don't have a background color as such. In fact, they are composed of images that Cocoa stitches together to make a coherent button image. So Cocoa can't recolor the images to your liking. Only the default button (the one with Return set as its key equivalent) will have a blue pulsing background.

What it sounds like you want to do will involve subclassing `NSButtonCell` and doing your own drawing. If you wanted to recolor the button images to get the effect you want, you can use the excellent [Theme Park](https://www.geekspiff.com/software/themepark.1.html) utility to extract copies of Apple's button images and use those. I'll admit to having done this myself in order to "steal" certain interface elements that aren't otherwise accessible, such as the scrollers from iTunes.

Comment: That explains why I can't just modify the background property. Theme Park is a real gem!

Comment: Any idea as to how to do this on Mountain Lion? Theme Park requires Leopard.

Answer (score 42):

Assuming everything is hooked up in IB for your borderless button.

```
// *.h file
IBOutlet NSButton* myButton;

// *.m file
[[myButton cell] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
```

Note from the [setBackgroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbuttoncell) documentation:

> "The background color is used only when drawing borderless buttons."

If this won't do it for you then you'll need to override NSButton and implement the drawing yourself.

Good Luck.

Comment: This works great on most of my windows. Any idea why it doesn't work on an NSWindow with an NSToolbar that swaps it's NSViews in and out? The buttons on those 'swappable' NSViews don't seem to be affected at all by the background color and yet I can change the text color of them just fine =(

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with swift.  I did'n't see the setbackgroundcolor method

Comment: That property on NSButtonCell is still there in Swift. Should be something like `(button.cell as? NSButtonCell)?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red`

Answer (score 20):

Here is another possible way to do this:

```
    let button = NSButton()
    button.title = ""
    button.bezelStyle = .texturedSquare
    button.isBordered = false //Important
    button.wantsLayer = true
    button.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: How to set the colour for button background including title part.Without title it works fine but how to include title as well

Comment: @PrithviVenu for that, you can use NSMutableAttributedString for attributedTitle. Check Naren's answer.

Comment: Yeah bro but My string is unicode ( has emoji's). So If Im not wrong we can't use NSMutableAttributedString on unicode strings right?

Comment: @PrithviVenu Emoji? You cannot change style of emoji as far as I know. You just need to grab emoji from lib using cmd+crtl+space, if you cannot find the one you want to use, then create image based button.

Comment: To be precise this is the text I need to change background for inside button  "Know More ▼ ". this down triangle was the emoji I meant , sorry I could have been more precise by calling it an arrowhead over an emoji. But I'm pretty sure the text colour can be changed but how to change the background colour of the button with text "Know More ▼ "

Comment: you're my lifesaver > worked perfectly on swift's version 4.1

Answer (score 15):

If anyone face problem for storyboard setup then for reference check: You can set properties directly to NSButton as shown below

:
[image]

Result :
  [image]

Comment: awesome, it's easier than other

Answer (score 9):

I've created a `NSButton` subclass called `FlatButton` that makes it super-easy to change button background color, text color, icon color, borders and other types of styling, from Interface Builder:

https://github.com/OskarGroth/FlatButton

[image: FlatButton for macOS]

Comment: Thanks for the awesome work. I'm still amaze how little customization there is for macOS UI elements. By the way, is it possible to use your FlatButton as a ToggleButton?

Comment: @SteveBegin Thanks! Yes, there is a isMomentary option.

Comment: Amazing work - but when I try add icons to the buttons they seem to og out of proportion.

Comment: @MobileBloke See answer on your ticket.

Comment: Thanks - It looks like you need to use the correct proportions for the current implementation as there is no resizing behaviour. @Oskar - the issue I found is that the text positioning of the button also needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Mark's answer is correct. But if doing it by code will be messy for you, then another way to do it is to set it directly in interface builder.

1. Find the button in interfaceBuilder and click on it.
2. On the object browser section of interface builder you will see the button that you clicked on has a dropdown disclosure icon. Click on it. It will then show you the NSButtonCell of the NSButton. Click on it.
3. With the NSButtonCell selected, Click on the Identity-Inspector.
4. In the Identity-inspector look for the section called `User Defined Runtime Attributes`
5. Click on the little plus (+) sign to add a value. The Value will show to have 3 properties. **(A)** keyPath **(B)** Type **(C)** Value
6. Change the keyPath to: `backgroundColor`. Change the type to: `Color`. Change the value to: what ever color you want (a color picker will be displayed)

Done.

Comment: Logically this should work but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Remember to set the button to borderless.

Comment: - I'm not saying this doesn't work (Xcode 8.2.1) but after spending nearly an hour on it, it didn't, no matter what I changed, just doesn't work

Comment: @swift nub could you please post the source code here (storyboard source) as this won't work:

`<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
  <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="color" keyPath="backgroundColor">
    <color key="value" red="0.90" green="0.18" blue="0.15" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
  </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>`

Comment: @PiniCheyni - nothing works as expected on Xcode that is a poor attempt to create an IDE and specially in Interface Builder that is a crappy attempt to creating something that builds interfaces.

Comment: This method works in Xcode 9 when you apply the steps on the NSButton itself, instead of the nested NSButtonCell object.

Comment: If it is a push on / push off button how do you change the background depending on the state?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you can do like this:

```
(button.cell as! NSButtonCell).isBordered = false
(button.cell as! NSButtonCell).backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: Beware that `The background color is used only when drawing borderless buttons.`

Answer (score 2):

When using macOS 11 or newer, you can use the `bezelColor` property when you have a button with `bezelStyle` set to `.rounded` or `regularSquare` in code, or when the button style is set to 'Push' or 'Bezel' in the interface designer of Xcode.

```
let button = NSButton()
button.title = "Example"
button.bezelStyle = .rounded // or .regularSquare
button.bezelColor = .controlAccentColor
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to create a view behind the button and set the colour of that. This creates the view with the same frame and the puts the button on top of the view. I use a tag on the button to make sure we only add the view once, so the method can be called repeatedly when drawing the UI.

I've included my code for setting the text colour.

Change the colour and alpha as desired:

```
NSColor *colour = [NSColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5] ;
[self styleButton:button colour:colour] ;

-(void) styleButton:(NSButton *)button colour:(NSColor *)colour {

    [self setButton:button fontColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

    if(button.tag == 9901) return ;

    button.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyleTexturedSquare ;
    [button setBordered:NO];

    NSView *b2 = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:button.frame] ;
    [button.superview addSubview:b2] ;

    b2.layer.backgroundColor = colour.CGColor;

    [button removeFromSuperview];
    [b2.superview addSubview:button];

    button.tag = 9901 ;
}

-(void) setButton:(NSButton *)button fontColor:(NSColor *)color {
    NSMutableAttributedString *colorTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[button attributedTitle]];
    [colorTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:NSMakeRange(0, button.attributedTitle.length)];
    [button setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these great answers.
I've compiled an NSButton subclass that makes it easy to set background color, border attributes (color, width, corners), and title attributes (color, font).

Feel free to use:
https://github.com/philfung/osx-dudley/blob/master/DudNSButton.swift

Comment: Nice work - thanks for sharing this.  You might want to update for latest version of Swift as it doesn't seem to run anymore

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking at this. This code works in Swift 5...

```
button.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
```

... you have to set needsLayer or add a layer in the nib first. It works with borders as well.

Answer (score -1):

you can choose your own color by clicking "Other..." option from color paletteUse "#colorLiteral" to select the color from the GUI color palette.

Button.layer?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4797514677, blue: 0.9984372258, alpha: 1)

[image: see image]

Answer (score -11):

UIElement(Element is of anything Like Button,view....)

UIElement *varname;

```
[varname setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0]];
```

eg:
UIButton *pButton;

```
[pButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: That won't help for an NSButton.