# Prevent Push Button from taking on background color in Dark Mode?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-darkmode

Put a Push Button on a custom NSView that has a background color, and in Light Mode, the button background remains white (both buttons are Push style with the default Tint) — but switch to dark mode and now the button takes on the background behind it.

[image: Button background color light mode vs. dark mode]

Note the button (top right in image) color on a View that does not have a background color set looks as expected.

Is there a way to make a Push Button behave the same way in Dark Mode and not take on the color of the NSView behind it?

Comment: What kind of "why" is this? Are you asking for why Apple did it this way? That would fall into the realm of speculation.

Comment: That's a really good point, @matt — I'm more surprised by the behavior than anything and am looking to see if anyone has helpful info.

Comment: I'm surprised too, but Stack Overflow is not a venue for expressing surprise (or disapproval) about Cocoa and its behavior.

Comment: Changed question @matt so it's a little less philosophical; thanks for your help with that.

Comment: Excellent, well done! Thanks for doing that.

Comment: OK so now I'd say this is a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017468/change-background-color-of-nsbutton. Changing the background color of an NSButton is not easy and has been well studied. :)

Comment: I disagree, @matt — I'm not trying to change the button to a specific color, just trying to get the button to behave the same way in Dark Mode that it does in Light Mode.

Comment: Yes, but the way you would do that is presumably to change its background color.

Comment: Is "behave the same way" white buttons? In Dark Mode both buttons are translucent and the gray button also takes on the color behind it.