# How do I change the color of a NSButton checkbox?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have a `NSButton` checkbox style and want to change the background color in the checkbox, both when state is .on and when state is off. Similar to the calendars list in macOS Calendar app.

Any hints on how to do that?

A `NSButton` with checkbox style consist of a checkbox and some text. If I set the background color of the NSButton everything BUT the checkbox is changed to have the color. That is the text gets the background color but the check box still have white background when unchecked and blue background when checked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change background color of NSButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017468/change-background-color-of-nsbutton)

Comment: Unfortunately not. See my edit in the question.

Comment: Then the only way to do that is if you subclass it and draw your own custom button, as indicated in one of the answers.