# Background color of NSButton doesn't changes & option not present in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard, viewcontroller

Unlike my colleague, who has **Bezel color** option [image: colleague's xcode], I don't have it in my xcode [image]

& when even when I try to use this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017468/change-background-color-of-nsbutton) approach by changing colors from creating a "Key Path", it doesn't change nor does it change with swift code in VC:

```
  let button = NSButton()
    button.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: Have you tried copying all code in the second answer, including the `//Important` part?

Comment: Yes! Yet nothing changed.